# Debug prepare statement vs string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, depuración

Normalmente cuando estoy programando algunas consultas suelo hacer esto:

```php
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tb WHERE $fl=:value";
$stmnt=$pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmnt->execute([':value'=>$val]);
```

Pero esto es php, si mi consulta falla pero no genera ningún error por que la sintaxis se cumplió, normalmente obtengo un `null` o `false`, lo que me lleva a hacer una depuración paso a paso.

Para tal caso en donde haga la depuración paso a paso en php suelo hacer un `echo` de mi `string`:

```php
$query = "SELECT * FROM Tabla WHERE Campo:=Valor;";
echo $query;
```

Pero aun así la salida no me incluye los valores de mi consulta, entonces tengo que hacer un apaño como:

```php
var_dump([$query,$valor]);
```

**Entonces si no veo el error a simple vista** y quiero evaluar si la consulta no tiene errores de sintaxis en el workbench debo ejecutar un string similar a:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Tabla WHERE Campo=Valor;
```

por lo tanto tengo manualmente que crear el string que voy a ejecutar en el workbench.

---

En este escenario al ser sencillo es fácil; pero en consultas más complejas donde hay múltiples joins, etc es engorroso tener que convertir el código php a una salida y luego darle el formato mysql para hacer cualquier validación que no arroje un error o excepción php.

¿Cual es el método común para hacer ***debug de sintaxis*** de sentencias mysql o sql en php?

¿***Es posible obtener el string de la consulta desde el objeto*** `$stmnt` sin necesidad de recrearla manualmente o es obligatorio hacerlo de forma manual?

Comment: Tu pregunta no es muy clara. Si hablamos de una sentencia que se genera en un contexto PHP, digamos que toma variables y cosas por el estilo, lo propio sería construir la consulta, hacer `echo` de la misma, copiar/pegar y probarla en el entorno SQL. Pero, si lo pensamos bien, esto no tiene sentido. Si estás escribiendo código PHP se supone que es con fines de crear un programa independiente, en el cual, entre otras cosas, debes verificar el estado de las consultas SQL, si fallaron o no. Entonces, ¿qué sentido tiene querer probar esa consulta directamente en entorno SQL?

Comment: *`cuando en php a lo mejor solo obtengo un false o null`*. A eso  me refiero precisamente. El sentido del programa PHP es evaluar ese `false` o `null` en el contexto de una aplicación, para mostrar un mensaje adecuado al usuario. No tiene gran interés la consulta en sí misma, o probarla en entorno SQL. En etapa de depuración usarás `errorInfo()` u otra herramienta, según el entorno de desarrollo PHP, para saber lo que está fallando. Es más, querer obtener la sentencia SQL que se produciría para probarla en entorno SQL te hace perder el tiempo, retrasando el desarrollo.

Comment: ¿Qué quiere decir fullstack? He leído de nuevo la pregunta y no le veo sentido. ¿Hablamos de depurar código? Usa las herramientas que te proporciona el entorno de desarrollo en el que estás trabajando para esos fines, querer sí o sí reproducir la consulta que se generaría es perder el tiempo y poco eficiente (por la dificultad que ello supone y porque los datos son dinámicos, puede fallar con un dato y con otro no). ¿Hablamos de la lógica de la aplicación en sí misma? Acopla el código a una política de manejo de errores.

Comment: @A.Cedano solo hace falta que recomiendes que borre todo y vuelva a hacerlo en laravel o algun framework. por favor trata de responderme con los elementos que te doy ... no de inventarle algo que no tengo... o de sugerir algo que nisiquiera agregas la documentacion ...

Comment: Te lo vengo diciendo hace rato, los elementos que das y la pregunta que planteas, no veo por donde agarrarla y ese es el problema. En mi último comentario he tratado de ayudarte a aterrizar, pero no hay manera. Retomemos, considerando que Stackoverflow tiene como norma que te limites a un problema por pregunta y que aportes un ejemplo mínimo y verificable. Entonces, para aclararnos: ¿Estamos hablando de depuración de código o de manejo de errores dentro de la aplicación que estás desarrollando en PHP? Si es lo primero: usa las herramientas que el entorno te ofrece, todos los entornos ...

Comment: ... te permiten formas eficaces de depuración. No te estoy diciendo que pases el programa a tal o cual framework, sino que uses las herramientas adecuadas para depurar. Querer sacar el código de un sitio para probarlo en otro es absurdo, que es lo que parece pretendes hacer.

Comment: Si hablamos de manejo de errores dentro de la aplicación (por ejemplo, para informar al usuario que usará esa aplicación), deberás programar código en PHP que verifique los estados `null` o `false` de las consultas emitiendo mensajes de error adecuados... es decir, incorporar tu código a una política de manejo de errores. Como podrás comprender, no es útil, en ninguno de los dos casos expuestos, sacar el código de un contexto (PHP en este caso) para probarlo en otro contexto (SQL). Es por eso que digo no le veo sentido a tu pregunta.

Comment: Vuelve a leer mis comentarios y dime en cuál de ellos te he dicho que cambies algo ¿? No te encasquilles, tómate 5 minutos, respira y vuelve a analizar el problema. Hay intención de ayudarte, pero estás planteando algo sin sentido a mi juicio.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138584/discussion-between-arcanisgk507-and-a-cedano).

Comment: De tus dos preguntas, según la última edición: la primera es **basada en opiniones** y la respuesta parcial a la segunda es **Sí**, aunque la forma en que terminas la pregunta da cancha a opiniones.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque es demasiado amplia (dos preguntas en una), la primera pregunta está basada en opiniones y la respuesta a la segunda pregunta es "Sí", entrando en el campo de preguntas basadas en opiniones por esto: *o Es obligatorio hacerlo de forma manual*.

Comment: @A.Cedano no se cual es tu dolor; la pregunta tiene dos respuestas validas y no es ni amplia ni basada en opiniones como aseguras...

Comment: @A.Cedano te invite a un chat para discutirlo y preferis seguir llenando el post de comentarios sin sentido que no aportan nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para php hay muchos metodos de debug casi puede ser basado en opiniones pero en realidad tenemos solo 2 grandes grupos para hacer debug desde php:

1. Todo lo que se haga por herramientas, librerias, plugin y depuracion paso a paso son correctas y cada una tendra su alcance; pero tendras sus limitaciones en cuanto a informacion, tiempo desperdiciado e inteligibilidad, como lo indica [Solrac](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/552217/46896).
2. Nativamente php y su driver PDO ofrece el metodo `debugDumpParams` el cual nos puede ayudar a evaluar de forma mas precisa, simple y consisa los datos manejados.

***Por ejemplo:***

```php
$consulta = $conexion->prepare("SELECT nameUser, namePost FROM users 
                               JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.user_id 
                               WHERE users.id = :id");
$consulta->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$consulta->execute();
var_dump($consulta->debugDumpParams());
```

***De lo cual obtendras:***

```
SQL: [96] SELECT nameUser, namePost FROM users JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.user_id WHERE users.id = :id
Sent SQL: [94] SELECT nameUser, namePost FROM users JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.user_id WHERE users.id = 1
Params:  1
Key: Name: [3] :id
paramno=-1
name=[3] ":id"
is_param=1
param_type=1
NULL
```

***Teniendo entonces:***

***SQL:*** el query enviado a solicitar el Id de ejecucion. 
***Sent SQL:*** la sentencia Sql Ejecutada, incluyendo la concatenacion de texto de las variables. 
***y otros datos relevantes*** como la cantidad de *parametros*, las *llaves*, *etc*.

Documentacion: [link](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php)

***Respuestas:***

1. Es poco conocidad pero ***si existe un metodo estandar*** dentro de php; Si usa debugDumpParams.
2. Si hay forma como lo decia usa debugDumpParams y ***no es obligatorio, el mismo metodo te brindara el string que se requiere***.

Answer (score 2):

Cuando ejecutas un query preparado no hay como tal una consulta final. Cuando ejecutas `$pdo->prepare()` le estás diciendo a SQL:

> Aquí hay un query que usa estos parámetros, dame un identificador para él.

Cuando ejecutas `$stmnt->execute()` le estas diciendo a SQL

> Para este identificador, acá están los parámetros, quiero el resultado.

Puedes revisar el log del servidor SQL directamente para saber los parámetros que le llegaron pero te va a mostrar lo mismo que tienes en tu código:

```
QUERY = "SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE campo=:value"
:value = "valor"
```

Otra opción es que uses un **debugger** que te muestre el valor de tus variables mientras se ejecuta tu script, de esta manera puedes colocar un breakpoint en la variable que deseas ver, en este caso `$sql` y tal vez otro breakpoint en `execute()` para ver los valor que le estás pasando.

Si solamente quieres ver el query que envías siempre puedes mandar un `print_r($sql)`, un `exit($sql);` o un `throw new Exception($sql)`, hay muchas alternativas.

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Agregaría que, querer obtener la cadena de la sentencia que se estaría ejecutando para probarla en el entorno SQL no es otra cosa que perder el tiempo, simplemente, es mejor usar las herramientas de depuración que ofrece el entorno en el que estás desarrollando el código.

Comment: @Solrac he hecho una actualizacion a mi publicacion por favor revisala nuevamente para que la tengas en cuenta si te hace falta agregar algo ta que la verdad aunque tu respuesta es completa no deja de ser un workaround.

Comment: Creo que ya encontre la solucion nativa de php XD gracias igualmente por el aporte.